# Builder is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Why?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, abstract-class, mapbox-android

I'm trying to implement one of Mapbox's examples. They have an options builder implemented in the way shown below. But when I try to build it I get the error

> error: Builder is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>
> MapboxNavigationOptions options = new MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder().navigationNotification(customNotification).build();

I don't understand why this is exactly? Isn't this the way this class is supposed to be used?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        routeRefresh = new RouteRefresh(Mapbox.getAccessToken(), (RefreshCallback) getApplicationContext());

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CustomNavigationNotification customNotification = new CustomNavigationNotification(context);
        MapboxNavigationOptions options = new MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder().navigationNotification(customNotification).build();

        navigation = new MapboxNavigation(
                this,
                Mapbox.getAccessToken(),
                options
        );

        navigation.addMilestone(new RouteMilestone.Builder()
                .setIdentifier(BEGIN_ROUTE_MILESTONE)
                .setInstruction(new BeginRouteInstruction())
                .setTrigger(
                        Trigger.all(
                                Trigger.lt(TriggerProperty.STEP_INDEX, 3),
                                Trigger.gt(TriggerProperty.STEP_DISTANCE_TOTAL_METERS, 200),
                                Trigger.gte(TriggerProperty.STEP_DISTANCE_TRAVELED_METERS, 75)
                        )
                ).build());
        customNotification.register(new MyBroadcastReceiver(navigation), context);
    }
```

Comment: Not `new MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder()`, it should be `MapboxNavigationOptions.builder()`

Comment: no `new`  keyword, lowercase B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the `new` keyword and using `MapboxNavigationOptions.builder()` instead of `new MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder()`.